# Async Storage to store theme in React native

Tags: react-native

I've set up a theme using context but I want to save the theme after the user has restarted the app. I'm new to data storage so I would need some help in how to write this code in Async Storage for specific case as I'm a bit confused on how to get it working. Thank you! (I've cleaned up a lot of code to only include the relevant things, so thats why it looks slim)

**Under App.js**

```
import ThemeContext, {themes} from './contexts/ThemeContext';
const [selectedTheme, setSelectedTheme] = useState(themes.arctic)

const changeTheme = (theme) =>{
  if (theme === "dark"){
  setSelectedTheme(themes.dark)} 
  else if (theme === "light") {
  setSelectedTheme(themes.light)
  }
  else if (theme === "red") {
  setSelectedTheme(themes.red)
  }

<ThemeContext.Provider value={{selectedTheme, changeTheme}}>
  <....>
  <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings}/>
```

**Under Settings (if this code is needed, this is where I call the changeTheme function)**

```
const handlePress = (theme) => {
    changeTheme(theme)}


<ThemeBadge color="white" onPress={()=>handlePress("light")}/>
<ThemeBadge color="black" onPress={()=>handlePress("dark")}/>
<ThemeBadge color="red" onPress={()=>handlePress("red")}/>
```

Comment: Do you use Expo or React Native CLI?

Comment: Expo! Is there a difference in the Async setup for these?

Comment: Expo  Team provide their own Async Storage Library, It just recommended by Expo - https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/

Comment: Ah okay,  but for simple things like theme where it doesn't matter if it's encrypted - could I still use async storage then?

Comment: You don't need to encrypt theme value - Treat this theme value like a traditional web cookie. They're just user preferences

Comment: yes but if I want to save the theme value, I would need to use either async storage or secure store - does it matter which one I use for that?

Comment: Change solution I authored

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241573/discussion-between-byiringiro-emmanuel-and-ollie).

Answer (score 1):

As you're using Expo, install `expo-secure-store`. Let we use custom hook to easily manage app theme preference.

```js
import * as SecureStore from "expo-secure-store";
import { useeEffect, useState } from "react";

function useAppTheme() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useTheme("light");

  async function updateTheme(key = "theme", value) {
    await SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, String(value).toString());
  }

  async function getTheme(key = "theme") {
    let result = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(key);
    if (result) {
      setTheme(result);
    } else {
      console.error("App could not get theme.");
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => getValueFor("theme"), []);

  return { theme, getTheme, updateTheme };
}

export default useAppTheme;
```

later in code, use hook

```js
const App = ()=>{
const {theme, updateTheme} = useAppTheme

const changeTheme = async (theme) =>{
  if (theme === "dark"){
await updateTheme("theme",themes.dark)

  setSelectedTheme(themes.dark)} 
  else if (theme === "light") {

await updateTheme("theme",themes.light)
  setSelectedTheme(themes.light)
  }
  else if (theme === "red") {

await updateTheme("theme",themes.red)
  setSelectedTheme(themes.red)
  }

<ThemeContext.Provider value={{selectedTheme, changeTheme}}>
  <....>
  <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings}/>


}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't quite follow in the "const {theme, updateTheme} = useAppTheme" - is it supposed to look like this?

Comment: Yeah, Dont' confuse with `[theme,setTheme] = useState()`, this is custom hook and we can return object instead array